What are the parts of speech for "welcome" in the following sentences?
What are the parts of speech for "welcome" in the following sentences?

Welcome to my place!
Welcome to visit my place!
Welcome to join us!

Chatgpt says that the first one is an interjection, and the other two are adjectives. Does it make sense?
Merriam Webster says that
welcome

interjection
—used to express a greeting to a guest or newcomer upon arrival


adjective
1
: received gladly into one's presence or companionship
was always welcome in their home
2
: giving pleasure : received with gladness or delight especially in response to a need
a welcome relief
3
: willingly permitted or admitted
he was welcome to come and go
—W. M. Thackeray
4
—used in the phrase "You're welcome" as a reply to an expression of thanks


None of these are clauses and so not "complete sentences" In particular 2 and 3 look like the ends of sentences, they are fragments.

Welcome. That's an interjection. All the others, are not. And 2) needs a verb: You are welcome to visit my place.

@JamesK The first one seems complete, it's something you might say to visitors. The others are incomplete, you would say "You are welcome to ."
